# How to create second MongoDB service in the same instance (ubuntu 18.04)?

Tags: mongodb

I have an instance in which mongodb.service is running

My plan is to create a second service (in the same server) to store some personal data, which can't be stored in the original mongodb.

So, I have followed the below procedure.

```
1. created a new db path
dbpath=/var/lib/mongodb2

2. created a new logPath.
logpath=/var/log/mongodb2/mongodb2.log

3.created a new config file.
config file -- /etc/mongodb2.conf

4. changed the port in the config file mongodb2.conf
port = 27019

5. created a new mongodb service
cp /etc/init.d/mongodb   /etc/init.d/mongodb2

6. edited /etc/init.d/mongodb2 (config path and others)
```

Then i have checked the second service status

```
sudo service mongodb2 status
```

But i got this issue,

> Unit mongodb2.service could not be found.

Please help

Comment: check this page. https://medium.com/@akshay2gud/creating-multiple-instances-of-mongodb-on-server-and-setting-replication-of-database-5ead59e1e4d4

Answer (score 0):

```
cd /lib/systemd/system
cp mongod.service mongod2.service
vim mongod2.service
```

change the line as ->

```
ExecStart=/usr/bin/mongod --config /etc/mongod.conf -> 
ExecStart=/usr/bin/mongod --config /etc/mongod2.conf
```

then

```
sudo service mongod2 start
```

activate on startup

```
sudo systemctl enable mongod
```